# Commas and single spaces between Fibonacci Numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new on Javascript and I have some troubles. How can I put commas and spaces   between fibonacci numbers? How can I split them ?

```
<script>

document.write("<h1 align='center'> SE 480 </h1>");
var name = "***";
var age = *** ;
document.write("Hi. My name is " +name+ " and I am " +age+ " years old.");

var i;
var fib = []; 

fib[0] = 0;
fib[1] = 1;

for(i=2; i<=30; i++)
{
   fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-1];
   document.write(fib[i]);
}




</script>
```

Comment: `document.write(fib[i]+', ');` . Also, your age variable is missing the quotes

Comment: Woaw. Thanks a lot. Now i think, it is simple ;) Yeah , i see it but my problem is solved thanks again.

Comment: @juvian: No, that will leave a dangling comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `document.write` from the loop and instead use this at the end:

```
document.write(fib.join(", "));
```

...if it's okay to include the `0` and `1` entries at the beginning. `join` returns a string with the entries separated with the string you provide (*without* a dangling one at the end).

If it's not okay to have `0` and `1` at the beginning, then:

```
document.write(fib.slice(2).join(", "));
```

(The `slice` creates a new array skipping the first two entries.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code where u write document.write

```
 document.write(fib[i]+', ');
```